# Migrating from cassandra 2.1 to scylla 4.5

Tags: cassandra, database-migration, scylla

made:

1. `nodetool flush` (on cassandra)
2. `nodetool snapshot name_snapshot` (on cassandra)
3. `cqlsh [IP] "-e DESC SCHEMA" > orig_schema.cql`  (on cassandra)
4. `cqlsh [IP] --file 'orig_schema.cql'` (on scylla)
5. `while IFS= read -r d; do sstableloader -cph 14 -j 14 -nb -nx -d [IP] ${d}/ done < <(find /dir_snapshot/keyspace/* -prune -type d)`

But the data is written to the cassandra (it is impossible to stop the application from writing to the cassandra),
how can I transfer/throw up the increment in scylla?
I understand that the application can be configured to write to both Cassandra and Scylla, but now the gap between the data is 4 months.
It is logical to transfer the changes in data which have accumulated via 4 months and then redirect the application into Scylla.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what you eluded to already - if you can't take the application down for maintenance you will have to do the switch-over using the application.

The typical path here would be to change the application code to write to two clusters at once (Cassandra & Scylla) while continuing to read from Cassandra.

While this is going you can recover data up to the point where the double-writing was deployed into Scylla.

Once the Scylla Cluster and the Cassandra cluster contain the same amount of data you'll change the application to read and write from Scylla and decommission the Cassandra cluster

```
Step 1: Write C & S -> Read C
Step 2: Migrate old Data C -> S
Step 3: Write S -> Read S
```